# Сбор временных отрезков в ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filter, asp

Есть один метод и я хочу посмотреть какое время затрачивается на его работу. Делаю я это через фильтры но не совсем понятно как они работают:

Вот сам метод который мы будем тестировать:

```
[TimeMetric( Name = nameof(ExcelToDataTable) )]
public DataTable ExcelToDataTable()
{
    // много кода
}
```

А вот реализация фильтра да подсчета вмени:

```
public class TimeMetricAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // Имя метода который мы сичтаем
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Stopwatch stopWatch;

    public TimeMetricAttribute()
    {
        Name = "Неизвестно";
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext )
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format( "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10 );

        // Ну тут временное решение, потом буду писать куда-нибуть в базу
        Debug.WriteLine( $"\n\n{Name}: RunTime {elapsedTime}\n");
    }
}
```

Я все правильно про фильтры понял или это бред?
Проблема в том что это не работает, фильтр видимо не вызывается...

Фильтры только к методам контроллера применимы или можно и к своим 
методам бизнес логики их применять?

Если нельзя, то существует ли какой-то механизм позволяющий вызывать какие-то действия до вызова целевого метода и после?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться механизмом трассировки, встроенным в asp.net
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Включение этой опции затронет только .cs файлы, так что для cshtml придётся ещё добавить следующее:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <trace autoflush="true">
     <listeners>
       <add name="textLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="app.log"  />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Подробная справка доступна в MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Не совсем понятно как это решает мою проблему. Задача в том что бы не замусоривать код, атрибутами добавить слежку за несколькими методами.

Comment: Вы увидите время работы абсолютно всех контроллеров. Дальше остаётся только спарсить из логов. В приведённой справке указано, как делать тоже самое не конфигурацией, но кодом. Вы можете написать свой атрибут, который будете весить на методы, а внутри писать в лог трассировки

Comment: мне кажется что подобная трассировка ASP.NET удобна при дебагинге. А если я хочу собирать метрики в продакшн версии?

Comment: Вы можете это делать и в продакшн, не вижу здесь проблем. Боитесь, что упадёт производительность?

Comment: Нет, боюсь этой магии)