# Атрибуты в C# запускающие функции до и после метода под атрибутом

Tags: c#

Подскажите существует-ли механизм который позволит пометить какой-либо метод атрибутом, что бы при запуске метода с начало срабатывала  функция из атрибута и после завершения работы метода срабатывала другая функция из атрибута.

```
[AttrFunc] // Тут запускаеться 2 функции одна до исполнения Method() вторая после
public void Method()
{
    // код
}
```

Comment: А не проще обернуть все три функции в еще одну функцию, а не связываться со всякими извращениями?

Comment: Это возможно с помощью AOP.

Comment: @Сергей конечно легче и конечно я так и сделал, но это смешивание бизнес логики и логики не относящейся к предметной области меня не радует

Comment: Возможно поможет Fody? https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody

Comment: Возможно поможет Fody? https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос не про asp.net, неплохой способ это сделать - использовать [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)

Почитайте [документацию](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator).

Comment: Почему единственный? AOP-фреймворков немало есть для .NET.

Comment: Я исправил свой комментарий, чтобы угодить вам

Comment: Крутая штука спасибо! А если ASP.NET ?

Comment: в ASP.NET фильтры сделают то, что вам надо

Comment: @Anton Shakalo вот у меня проблема с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801919/%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-asp-net

Comment: Я уже вам там ответил)

Comment: @AntonShakalo да я понял только не понял почему у меня фильтр не работает )